# Azure SQL and my ASP.NET C#

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have made application ASP.NET C# and my connection string is as follows:

```
<add name="ASPNETDB" connectionString="Server=tcp:MYDATA.database.windows.net,1433;Database=MYDATA;User ID=MYDATA;Password=MYDATA;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Now it doesn't work at all, I mean I can't connect to my SQL server on Azure at all. When I want to login nothing happens, when I want to register nothing happens too. I get exception when I press to update DB, ie Publish->Settings-> Check box "Update database" Configure database updates . It seems to me that it doesn't work at all. The exception is of following type:
Error   22  Web deployment task failed. (Could not deploy package.
Unable to connect to target server.

Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXECUTING_METHOD.)     0   0

What should I do? Please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set firewall rule 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255. Even though my firewall rule was set for my address, somehow it didn't register, because communication was relying to my website-DB and ip address of my website wasn't included there too. So I put rule as said before and now it works like a charm. :-)

Comment: you are allowing every ip address open access to your Database?

Comment: Yes. Is there any reason why I shouldn't do so?

Comment: Firewalls exist for a reason; setting a firewall rule for 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255 is essentially the same as turning the firewall off.  The internet is the wild west security wise, and if someone discovers your system is vulnerable like that, they WILL take advantage of it.

Comment: Yes I agree to that. All please be noted this is only university project. If you want to make your app secure, please do exactly the same BUT only make for your ip : 192.144.41.1 192.144.41.1 for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend logging into the azure management portal and re downloading the publish profile for the application. If you are not working using a publish profile , then at least re download the connection string that is setup for the app and the DB. while in there check that the application (web site or VM) is up and running, and that the database it is connected to is also up and running.

Comment: I have checked all that symeon. I have made in portal.azure.com my own strings, that are similar to those in web.config in my application, checked that db and site works too. I don't know what else to do?

Comment: It could be a firewall issue - although when you publish from VS it normally sorts all of that for you.  Are you deploying to a web site or a vm ?

Comment: I am deploying to website, from VS, going Publish and it do all the rest for me.